# Is it possible to debug a Unity Android game directly on a device?

Tags: unity, android, debugging

I'm working on my game and every time I make changes to it I send the game to my mobile device to debug it.

I want to know how I can directly debug my game using an Android device instead of the MonoDevelop editor?

Comment: "using android device instead of android device?" I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: Only option I can thing off is to use logcat to see debug logs from android device if You want to see whats happening on it. Just use `adb logcat` command in your command prompt or `%YOUR_SDK_LOCATION%\platform-tools\adb logcat`. If Your on windows use it with .exe suffix `adb.exe logcat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear. If you want to use your Android device to control the game, you can set up a connection with Unity and your device through USB, using the Unity Remote app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unity3d.genericremote&hl=bg

That way you don't have to wait for it to build and push to your device for every small change in your game.